# Can't open windows after deleting the partition that kali was installed on

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, grub

I have windows 10 installed on my pc and I decided to install kali linux besides windows, after I installed it I downloaded some things that corrupted kali linux, so i logged in to windows and deleted the partition that I installed kali linux on it, and that's to reinstall the kali linux, but after deleting the partition, I can't even log in to windows 10, it shows :
GRUB LOADING.
Welcome to GRUB!
error: no such device: 246ff576-893a-....
error: unknown filesystem
grub rescue>

Comment: Well, that you *can't open kali linux after deleting the partition that kali was installed on* shouldn't be a surprise because it's gone, that's the obvious consequence of having deleted it. That you're still booting the now non-working Kali entry it's no surprise either but you should be able to boot Windows directly by changing the bootloader at UEFI > Boot menu. What is surprising is someone trying to use such a specialized and very demanding in terms of prior knowledge Linux distro not knowing such basic stuff as the aforementioned trivialities.

Comment: I think you should rethink the Linux distro because clearly Kali isn't for you and it isn't even "designed" to be installed (although of course it can) but to be used as a live session.

Comment: Bruh... I'm not surprised because i can't open kali linux, because i wanted to delete it and install it again, but what made me be surprised is that i can't open windows

Comment: And yeah I'm not so knowledgeable about this thing but I'm still a beginner and trying to learn by my self

Comment: What do you mean by live session? I made a dual boot for kali

Comment: Why kali is designed to be used as a live session? I can't store anything this way

Comment: And also i tried to change the bootloader but it is still showing the grub

Comment: Thank you for listing all the reasons why you shouldn't be using Kali :) Obligatory reading: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Comment: When should i use kali? After i become a professional in using it? Or what do you mean? I'm just learning and i think this is normal to not know some basic stuff.

Comment: When? Have you read any of the answers from the link above?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you could follow these steps to rebuild the windows UEFI bootloader:
https://support.novabackup.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011403653-How-to-repair-the-EFI-bootloader-on-a-GPT-HDD-for-Windows-7-8-8-1-and-10

and after that you should be fine to reinstall linux

next time, don't delete the partition, just run the linux usb installer of your choice and let it's partition step do it's job

Comment: I actually used a windwos usb to fix the boot loader, but thank you very much for your answer, I will use this method next time when I face a similar problem

Comment: but what do you say about those replies from that person that is telling me that I shoudn't be using kali linux, I believe that I don't know anything about kali linux but it is not a reason to not learning it

Comment: ChanganAuto is right, but also wrong... while they are right about Kali and the expectation of it's user's not being linux learners, they are wrong that you shouldn't or can't use it as a beginner... Plus, your issue isn't really specifically related to Kali - this could have happened just about any linux distribution.
Personally, I think that Kali isn't the best linux distro choice for a beginner, but that's just like my opinion, man...

Comment: To answer your question about what a 'live session' is: A live session is when you run the system from a USB drive and don't install it to a hard drive.
You would do this for various reasons, but the two that stick out the most to me are: (1) portability/flexibility, and (2) ephemerality/non-persistence.  
1: you can take the usb drive to any computer, plug it in and boot to your live session
2: the only changes to the computer you run the live session on are ones that you make deliberately (if you mount and write to the internal drives of that PC)... everything else is lost

Comment: ps: you can set up persistence on your live session usb so when you install packages or make system config edits you don't lose them across live sessions, but there are other operational security, privacy, and logistical/practical considerations to be considered by doing so

Comment: thank you for the information about the live session, but can you suggest a good choice of a distro for a beginner?

Comment: i would suggest linux mint

Comment: ok thank you very much

Comment: you're welcome. I would appreciate it if you accepted my answer.

Comment: Done, i didn't know that i can do it, i would have done that before

Comment: thanks... you're here to learn